# The content became wrapped after I changed it

Tags: dart, rikulo

I changed the content of TextView, but it is displayed as wrapped. Am I doing wrong?

```
textView.text = “a new content”;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you changed the content, you have to notify the layout manager by invoking textView.requestLayout(). Please refer to "Force to Redo the Layout of a View" in [Layout Overview](http://docs.rikulo.org/rikulo/latest/Layouts/Fundamentals/Layout_Overview.html) for more information. Basically, the layout manager detects only the resize of the browser and the change of the view's visibility.

Of course, you can set the width by yourself. Then, whether to wrap is all up to the width and the content you set.